# Check what needs full trust

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hosting, signalr

I've just finished developing the core features of my site, and have now uploaded it to a host to test.

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

After tedious searching, I realised that it's because I developed in a full trust environment, and my stubborn host will only allow medium trust.

When I set medium trust in web.config, the debugger doesn't show what exactly needs the full trust environment.

Is there any way to clearly check this, or somehow force the site to co-operate?

I am using MVC with FormsAuthentication, Code-First Databasing, etc.

Comment: PS: I cannot include 'valid code' because I have no idea what code is causing the issue. So marking the question as off-topic because of that is a bit counter-productive.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/558389/542251

Comment: _"marking the question as off-topic because of that is a bit counter-productive"_ - it is required of you to do some research. Find out how you can debug and/or log trust issues, find the classes that you use that throw them, find out that ASP.NET medium trust is in the process of being deprecated, search contact with your host whether they support ASP.NET MVC, and so on. Close-votes aren't for fun, they're for ensuring quality questions. :-)

Comment: I understand that - but everything I've read so far only leads to 'ask your host for full trust' or 'here is how to set your site to medium'. Brakpoints don't help at all (after setting web.config to medium trust), as the exception gets thrown /somewhere/. And I didn't really think about logging until it was pointed out. Being a question and answer site, that helped a lot.

Comment: Yes, from the above error message, you need to run this on Full Trust. If not, it wont work

Answer (score 3):

After a LOT of trial and error, I have found the error.

Microsoft's SignalR requires full trust, and there is no way around it.

Disabling that fixes the issue.

**Edit**
It also seems that any library that will help the site out in the long run is out. If anyone is getting this error, simply disable (comment out) any tertiary library you use BEFORE altering your core code.

Breakpoints do not help at all, as after disabling SignalR, I had an error on a certain page. Setting a breakpoint didnt stop the code in the error event, as it turns out the Security Exception is thrown somewhere deep inside C#, and not brought to the top.

Comment: I approve this message. Medium trust is dead anyways

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

1. You could have **two web.config files**, one for debugging and one for publishing and testing under an environment that is as close as posible as your hosting environment.
2. Another option could be two have a **single config file with the medium trust set, and use logging to a file/event logger** to allow you to debug

Comment: @NewAmbition in case you need more details about logging and tracing I found this article http://odetocode.com/articles/294.aspx